# Lottie animations in Ionic 3 Loading Controller

Tags: ionic3, lottie

I am using the Lottie Animations in the in the IONIC 3 App. It works fine in a separate page but if i include it in the Loading Controller it doesn't render anything.

```
  this.lottieConfig = {
    path: 'assets/animations/lottie/material-wave-loading.json',
    autoplay: true,
    loop: false
  };


   this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
   spinner: 'hide',
   content: '<lottie-animation-view [options]="lottieConfig"></lottie- 
              animation-view>'
   });
   this.loading.present();
```

Did anyone try this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.